# What are the main drawbacks of exposing a DependencyProperty via a static property instead of a static field? (F#)

Tags: wpf, f#, dependency-properties

I found out that [F# 2.0 apparently doesn't support public static fields anymore](http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2010/10/01/public-static-fields-gone-from-f-2-0/), which makes impossible the standard way of implementing a `DependencyProperty`:

```
public static readonly FooProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(...);   // in C#
```

I don't quite like one [suggested work-around](http://stevehorsfield.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/creating-wpf-dependency-properties-in-fsharp/) for F# which involves declaring the `DependencyProperty` as a `static mutable val` and then initializing it with a `static do`... (or however exactly it goes).

I've tried exposing a `DependencyProperty` as a public static *property* instead of as a public static *field*, which seems to work just fine in a WPF application (I've tried data binding and style setters on the property, both with success):

```
type XY() =
   inherit Control()

   static let fooProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Foo", typeof<string>, typeof<XY>) 

   static member public FooProperty with get () = fooProperty  // see update below:
   //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  // not required!

   member public this.Foo with get (): string = this.GetValue(fooProperty) :?> string
                          and set (x: string) = this.SetValue(fooProperty, x)
```

Are there any notable drawbacks to publishing a dependency property as a property, instead of as a field? Because this code looks much cleaner to me than the suggested work-around.

---

**Update #1:** I just found that in the above code, `FooProperty` (the public read-only property) isn't even required. So one could drop the line I high-lighted in the above code example and things still work just fine. I'm now even more curious why people go to such lengths using `mutable val` etc. when it's apparently that simple? Am I missing something important?

---

**Update #2:** In a comment below, Robert Jeppesen provided a [hyperlink to an MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx) which mentions the following:

> *If you fail to follow this naming pattern* [ie. `Foo` → `FooProperty`] *, designers might not report your property correctly, and certain aspects of property system style application might not behave as expected.*

I put Expression Blend 4 to the test and found that it doesn't seem to be affected at all when the public static `FooProperty` is completely missing.

Comment: looks fine to me... but I don't do a lot of WPF

Comment: Regarding your update, That should mean that a public static field is not necessary in C# either?

Comment: @Robert, I suspect that there *might* be situations where the XAML compiler expects to find a `FooProperty` field and will complain if it doesn't; I could also imagine that the public field/property becomes more important with attached properties. But apparently yes, some things work fine without the public static field -- as long as you execute the `DependencyProperty.Register` somewhere, and as long as your getter/setter can refer to their backing `DependencyProperty` somehow.

Comment: @stakx - I was just going to write an answer regarding attached properties. I haven't tested, but I bet that an attached property relies on having a static public field. So that rules out removing your static member above, but will it work if you include it?

Comment: @stakx - MSDN about the link between DependencyProperty and its field name: "If you fail to follow this naming pattern, designers might not report your property correctly, and certain aspects of property system style application might not behave as expected."   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx

Comment: @Robert: Thanks for the link. I must say though that this resource is both helpful and confusing at the same time. Concerning the confusing part, it only states the *possible* consequences (... but how likely are they, really?) when the *naming* pattern isn't followed -- but is it just about the name, or is the fact that it is usually fields, not properties, just as important for the proper functioning of designers and other tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does make a difference whether you use a public static **field** or not.  But maybe not a significant difference, depending on your needs.  I will explain where WPF itself behaves differently, then mention a couple of other situations in which it might also be a problem.

**Effect on XAML parsing if you use a static property instead of a static field**

The only part of WPF itself that actually notices whether you used a static property or a static field is the XAML parser, and the only situation where it makes a difference is when the same property name is used at multiple levels.  This is because the existence of a static field with matching name and ending in "Property" is used to disambiguate between identically-named DependencyProperties at multiple levels.

One place you'll see a difference is if you define your property using a public static *property* (or nothing at all) and the ancestor class has a DependencyProperty the same name using a public static *field*, the ancestor class's property will be used instead of yours.

For example, suppose create a Control that has a DependencyProperty named "Language".  FrameworkElement already has a "Language" DependencyProperty, but as long as you follow the standard and use a public static *field*, that's ok:  Your "Language" property will take precedence.  But if you use a public static *property* instead, your XAML will end up setting the "FrameworkElement.Language" dependency property, not yours.

This could be a problem if, for example, a new version of WPF comes out that has a new dependency property defined on one of your base classes.  For example, if you are using a "Depth" property you've defined using a static field, and NET Framework 5.0 defines a "Depth" property on "Visual", your application won't work on the new version of NET Framework.

Another scenario where this may make a difference is when the class hierarchy is changed.  WPF tries to protect you from versioning issues in this case, but its protection goes away if you used a public static *property* instead of a public static *field*.  The simplest scenario is that you wrote a library and people are using your property.  If you used a public static *field* their compiled application will actually include your class name so there can be no mistake.  But if you used a public static *property* (or nothing at all) their compiled application will reference it using their derived class name.  So if the inheritance hierarchy changes or a new property is introduced in between, it could shadow your original property even in compiled code.  For example, this could be an issue if:

- YourControl is derived from ThirdPartyGrid
- YourControl was written when ThirdPartyGrid didn't have a "Language" field, so the compiled code references FrameworkElement.Language
- If the vendor of ThirdPartyGrid adds a "Language" dependency property it won't affect your application
- **But** if FrameworkElement.Language had been defined as a public static *property*, the vendor's addition would break your application

There are some even more esoteric situations where it can make a difference.

**Effects on designer tools**

As far as I can tell, neither Visual Studio nor Expression Blend behave any differently if you define the property using a public static *property* instead of a *field*, or even if you leave it out entirely, except when they encounter the XAML parser behavior mentioned earlier.

But it should be noted that there are many XAML development environments out there, and since the pattern of using static *fields* is so firmly established, they may rely on this.  So it is caveat emptor.

**Effects on WPF itself other than XAML parsing**

Except for the XAML parser, no part of WPF cares whether you have defined a public static property, field, or nothing at all.  You can use your DependencyProperties exactly the same way in each case.  However:

1. I know of no guarantee this will always be true, and
2. Third party code could easily rely on it

Comment: Wow, that was rather enlightening. Many thanks for your answer. One thing which thoroughly confuses me though is that you seem to suggest that the normal way of exposing a `DependencyProperty.Register(...)` is via public static *properties* -- but if you browse MSDN, or almost any other sample code, it's always *fields* (`public static readonly DependencyProperty BlahblahProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(...);`). How come that you seem to state the exact opposite?

Comment: Egads! I must have had a brain freeze, or maybe I was asleep. I knew exactly what I meant to say, but I said exactly the opposite. Sorry about that. I have corrected it in my answer. Yes, it is a public static *field* that is the convention and that triggers the additional behavior in the parser.